# Reduce data again with multiple keys

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I have a view which counts reports for each city

```
function (doc) {
  if(doc.type == "report")
  {
     emit(doc.city_name, null);
  }
}
```

And I reduce it with `_count` which produces these values:

```
{'key': 'South Tampa', 'value': 2}
{'key': 'Sebring', 'value': 19}
{'key': 'Satsuma', 'value': 3}
{'key': 'Palm Desert', 'value': 1}
{'key': 'Indio', 'value': 1}
```

At the moment I do a request with multiple keys to this view (for example `["Indio", "Satsuma"]`) and I sum them in python.

Is it possible to sum them with CouchDB directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Couchdb List function might be a possibility to achieve what you want.

http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.2/ddocs/ddocs.html#list-functions

To get a better impression on how  to use it this article might be helpfull.
http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/transforming.html

A list function which sums them:

```
function(head, req){ 
  i = 0; 
  while(row = getRow()){ i += row.value; } 
  send('{ \"total_count\":' + i +'}'); 
}
```

Comment: FYI: List functions are proposed for deprecation on the next major release.

Comment: Thanks for the info, can you post a link with a reference?